# How to show $\int_Q \varphi^2 (\Delta v)v_t = \int_Q |\nabla v|^2 \varphi \varphi_t - 2\int_Q (\nabla v \cdot \nabla \varphi) (\varphi v_t)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $Q=\bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}\Omega \times \{t\}$. I have seen this identity for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(Q)$ such that $0 \leq \varphi \leq 1$:

$$\int_Q \varphi^2 (\Delta v)v_t = \int_Q |\nabla v|^2 \varphi \varphi_t - 2\int_Q (\nabla v \cdot \nabla \varphi) (\varphi v_t)$$

How do I prove it?

I get the left hand sides equals
$$2\int_Q |\nabla v|^2 \varphi \varphi_t$$
but no idea what to do next.

Assume whatever smoothness of $v$ necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, using integration by parts
$$
\int_{Q}\varphi^2(\Delta v)v_t=
-\int_{Q}\nabla (\varphi^2 v_t)\cdot\nabla v=
-2\int_{Q}(\nabla\varphi\cdot\nabla v)\varphi v_t-\int_{Q}(\nabla v_t\cdot\nabla v)\varphi^2.
$$
But
$$
\int_{Q}(\nabla v_t\cdot\nabla v)\varphi^2=\frac{1}{2}\int_{Q}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\nabla v|^2\varphi^2=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{Q}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\varphi^2)|\nabla v|^2
=-\int_{Q}|\nabla v|^2\varphi\varphi_t.
$$
Note that there are not boundary terms, as $\varphi$ is compactly supported.

(Edited some typos)

Comment: Thanks! If I don't have $v_t(t) \in H^1$, I guess I can use some density argument to prove this, right?

Comment: On second thoughts it looks difficult to do this (if $v_t \not\in H^1(\Omega)$) via a density argument as we'd want to pass to the limit in the Laplacian term. I wonder if have you idea to do it?