# An equality that holds with $v_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ but its proof requires $v_t \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, bochner-spaces

Let $Q=(0,T)\times \Omega$. For all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(Q)$ such that $0 \leq \varphi \leq 1$, the following holds

$$\int_Q \varphi^2 (\Delta v)v_t = \int_Q |\nabla v|^2 \varphi \varphi_t - 2\int_Q (\nabla v \cdot \nabla \varphi) (\varphi v_t)$$
when $v \in L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega))$ such that $v_t \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$.

It has been claimed that this identity holds for all $v \in L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega))$ such that $v_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ (notice the weaker space the time derivative is in). Of course all terms in the identity make sense with $v$ in this weaker space, **BUT** the proof (see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692579/how-to-show-int-q-varphi2-delta-vv-t-int-q-nabla-v2-varphi-varph)) uses integrating by parts and one of the intermediary calculations includes the term $\nabla v_t$. So I don't see why the equality is true in the weaker case of $v_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ because the proof requires a stronger time derivative.

I am guessing a density argument is used to prove this for all functions in the weaker space. But I can't find a sufficiently smooth dense subset that will do the job because we need to pass to the limit in the Laplacian term on the left hand side. Can anyone tell me how this works? Is there a different way to get this identity maybe with a different proof to the one linked?

- This is related to a [Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158879/are-smooth-functions-dense-in-the-space-u-in-h1q-text-with-delta-ga) I posted.
- The source of the claim is Variational methods in the stefan problem by José-Francisco Rodrigues, in the proof of Proposition 4.7.

Comment: posting the comment as an answer... sry :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited after a quite lengthly comment discussion.

Let $X:=\left\{v\in L^{2}\left(0,T,H^{2}\right):v_{t}\in L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)\right\}$ and let $\left\|v\right\|_{X}:=\left\|v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}+\left\|\nabla v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}+\left\|\nabla^{2} v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}+\left\|v_{t}\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}$.

Let $Y:=\left\{v\in L^{2}\left(0,T,H^{2}\right):v_{t}\in L^{2}\left(0,T,H^{1}\right)\right\}$ and let $\left\|v\right\|_{Y}:=\left\|v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}+\left\|\nabla v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}+\left\|\nabla^{2} v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}+\left\|v_{t}\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}+\left\|\nabla v_{t}\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}$.

Your assumption is that for $v\in Y$ the following equation holds:

$\int_{Q}\varphi^{2}\left(\Delta v\right)v_{t}=\int_{Q}\left|\nabla v\right|^{2}\varphi\varphi_{t}-2\int_{q}\left(\nabla v\cdot \nabla\varphi\right)\varphi v_{t}$

Now this shall be generalised to $X$ by density. First note that $Y$ is dense in $X$:

$C^{\infty}$ is dense in $X$ respective $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{X}$, $C^{\infty}\subset Y$ and (obviously) $Y\subset X$. Thus we get $Y$ is dense in $X$ respective $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{X}$.

Now fix $v\in X$ and let $\left(v_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in Y$ such that $\left\|v-v_{n}\right\|_{X}\rightarrow 0$. This convergence implies:

- $\left\|\Delta v_{n}-\Delta v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}\rightarrow 0$
- $\left\|v_{nt}-v_{t}\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}\rightarrow 0$
- $\left\|\nabla v_{n}-\nabla v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}\rightarrow 0$

since $\varphi\in C^{\infty}$ is bounded this gives us, that all the integrants (all are products of $L^{2}$ functions converging strongly in $X$) are converging strongly in $L^{1}\left(0,T,L^{1}\right)$. The integral operator is continuous on $L^{1}$, so we can pass to the limit.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I'm still confused. So we have a sequence $v_n$ where we require $v_n \in L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega))$ and $(v_n)_t \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$ such that $v_n \to v$ in $L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega))$ and $(v_n)_t \to v_t$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$. If such a sequence exists then we can pass to the limit with no problem. So the question is, how do we know that such a sequence exists? How do we know that the space this sequence lives in is dense in $\{v \in L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega)) : v_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))\}$? It's the density result that I am unclear about.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by $v_{t}$? is it $v\left(t,\cdot\right)$? or $\partial_{t}v$? i've seen several meanings for this notation

Comment: I mean the $\partial_t v$, the weak time derivative.

Comment: i think i mixed things up. i used $H^{1}\left(0,T,H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\right)$

Comment: for the sequence $\left(v_{n}\right)_{t}\rightharpoonup v_{t}$ would be enough. is there maybe something bounded? (would be enough for weak subsequences)

Comment: I'm surprised that for $v\in L^{2}\left(0,T,H^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\right)$ $v_{t}$ even exists... I can embed $\mathbb{R} $ in $ H^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$ if $\Omega$ is bounded which would mean that $L^{2}\left(\left[0,T\right]\right)$ functions are once weak differentiable...

Comment: I agree one strong and one weak convergence is enough I think. I don't think anything bounded will help, we need a general result about dense subspaces I think.

Comment: do you get the t-differentiability because of a miniizing sequence of a functional including a term assuring it's existence? than i think it can work.

Comment: Well if we want a density result we want it to hold for all $v$ in the appropriate space, so I don't think one should assume anything about how we get existence of $v_t$.

Comment: ah lol actually i did *not* mix things up: you have $v\in L^{2}\left(0,T,H^{1}\right)$ and $v_{t}\in L^{2}\left(0,T,H^{1}\right)$ *which means* $v\in H^{1}\left(0,T,H^{1}\right)$ so what i suggested as answer should work. we can pass too the limit since all expressions are continuous in $v\in H^{1}\left(0,T,H^{1}\right)$ respective the appropriate norm: $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{H^{1}\left(0,T,H^{1}\right)}$. aditionally we can take an approximating sequence (by density) which we know the elementwise equality of.

Comment: We don't have $v_t \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$. It's only $L^2$ in space. Even if we did have what you wrote it still certainly is not enough to pass to the limit in the Laplacian term.

Comment: ok, ignore my notion about the $H^{1}$ spaces. the point is$\Delta v_{n}$ and $v_{nt}$ are strongly convergent in in $L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)$ so the right hand side is fine for convergence. $\left|\nabla v_{n}\right|$ is strongly convergent in $L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)$ so the first term on the lhs is also ok for passing to limits. $\nabla v_{n}$ and $v_{nt}$ are strongly convergent in $L^{2}$, too - so the last term is also fine. _You do not need any spatial derivatives of $v_{t}$ for this equation_

Comment: With your last comment, what you are saying is that some space $X$ of smooth functions (that the $v_n$ lie in) are dense in the space $\{ v \in L^2(0,T;H^2) \mid v_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2)\}$ which is endowed with the obvious norm. What is the space $X$, and how do you prove that it is dense? That is the issue.

Comment: approximate respective the following norm: $\left\|v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,H^{2}\right)}+\left\|v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,L^{2}\right)}$ (this would be the norm for the space $v$ comes from)
but with approximating functions out of the space with the following norm being finite (to make the equality hold for the sequence): $\left\|v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,H^{2}\right)}+\left\|v\right\|_{L^{2}\left(0,T,H^{1}\right)}$
prove density by smooth functions which are dense in the space for $v$ and since the space for the $v_{n}$ contains them and is contained in the space for $v$ it's also dense.

Comment: $C^{\infty}\subset X$ dense, $C^{\infty}\subset Y\subset X \Rightarrow Y\subset X$ dense

Comment: if you are daccord with that now, i will edit the answer, otherwise i will surrender :)

Comment: lol I'll have to get back to you :)

Comment: edited, hope its okay now.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm a bit busy atm but I will give this attention today/tomorrow.

Comment: OK, I think it looks good. But are you sure that "$C^\infty(Q)$ is dense in $X$"? I guess it is since we can probably define $X$ as closure of $C^\infty$ wrt. the $X$ norm. Anyway I think your answer is fine..

Comment: If the issue of density in the previous comment is resolved I would be happy. Let me read around a bit for that.

Comment: The density should work by convolution with a smooth mollifier (of class $C^{\infty}\left(\left[0,T\right]\times\Omega\right)$). I will check the convergence later, just came home and need a break :-)

Comment: convolution does not work i think, but i'd be suprised if it wouldnt be dense. will try to check evans tomorrow.